# Sorting of files according to file or folder

Tags: android

i have an array of names which have multiple files and folders...now i want to sort the names according to files and folders.all folders first and then all files should display.i have the variable to check whether on particular index of array their is file or folder.but unable to think the logic..
i am attaching some of my codes.

////////////////////////////////
case 0://Sort By Name
                        {

```
                        if(m_sortType == SORT_BY_NAME && temp==false)
                        {
                            m_sortType = SORT_BY_NAME;
                            m_sortOrder=SORT_ORDER_DESCENDING;
                            temp= true;
                            //Log.d("SORTING", "SORT - NAME - DES");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m_sortType = SORT_BY_NAME;
                            m_sortOrder=SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING;
                            temp=false;
                            //Log.d("SORTING", "SORT - NAME - AES");
                        }

                        //Log.d("SORTING", "Data bfore sort");
                        for (int k=0; k<m_adapter.m_env.m_count; k++)
                            //Log.d("SORTING DATA", k + ": " + m_adapter.m_env.m_fs.get(m_SortArray[k]).m_name);

                        m_adapter.sortListing(m_sortType,m_sortOrder);

                        //Log.d("SORTING", "Data after sort");
                        for (int k=0; k<m_adapter.m_env.m_count; k++)
                            //Log.d("SORTING DATA", k + ": " + m_adapter.m_env.m_fs.get(m_SortArray[k]).m_name);

                        //Refresh();
                        break;
                    }
```

////////////////
private  void sortListing(int sortType, int sortOrder)
        {
            m_sortType = sortType;
            m_sortOrder = sortOrder;
            Arrays.sort( m_SortArray , new Comparator() {

```
            public int compare(Integer a1, Integer a2)
            {

                if(m_sortType == SORT_BY_NAME)
                {
                    String s1 = null,s2 = null;
                    FileFolderEnum t2 = null;
                    FileFolderEnum t1 = null;
                    int i;
                    if(m_sortOrder==SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING)
                    {
                        s1 = m_env.m_fs.get(a1).m_name;
                        s2 = m_env.m_fs.get(a2).m_name;
                        t1 = m_env.m_fs.get(a1).m_type;
                        t2 = m_env.m_fs.get(a2).m_type;
                    }
                    else if(m_sortOrder==SORT_ORDER_DESCENDING)
                    {
                        s1 = m_env.m_fs.get(a2).m_name;
                        s2 = m_env.m_fs.get(a1).m_name;
                        t1 = m_env.m_fs.get(a2).m_type;
                        t2 = m_env.m_fs.get(a1).m_type;
                    }
                    //Log.d("SORTING COMPARE", "(" + Integer.toString(a1)+") s1: " + s1);
                    //Log.d("SORTING COMPARE", "(" + Integer.toString(a2)+") s2: " + s2);
                    if((t1.equals(CFileFolder.FileFolderEnum.FFE_FOLDER)&&(t2.equals(CFileFolder.FileFolderEnum.FFE_FOLDER))))
                    {
                         i=s1.compareToIgnoreCase (s2);
                    }
                     i=s1.compareToIgnoreCase (s2);

                    //Log.d("SORTING COMPARE", "s1.compareTo(s2): " + Integer.toString(i));
                    return i;
                }
```

///////////////////

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Code I pulled from my own file browser. Use as you wish. :

```
File[] directoryList = currentFolder.listFiles(); 
if (directoryList != null) {
   List<File> directoryListing = new ArrayList<File>();
   directoryListing.addAll(Arrays.asList(directoryList));
   Collections.sort(directoryListing, new SortFileName());
   Collections.sort(directoryListing, new SortFolder());
}


//sorts based on the files name
public class SortFileName implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
          return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
    }
}

//sorts based on a file or folder. folders will be listed first
public class SortFolder implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
         if (f1.isDirectory() == f2.isDirectory())
            return 0;
         else if (f1.isDirectory() && !f2.isDirectory())
            return -1;
         else
            return 1;
          }
}
```

Comment: (f1.isDirectory() && f2.isDirectory()) || (!f1.isDirectory() && !f2.isDirectory()) can be simplified to (f1.isDirectory() == f2.isDirectory)

Comment: Thank you very much, It really healped me a lot. @dymmeh

Comment: Why do you convert the `directoryList` array to a `List<File>`, instead of using `Arrays.sort(directoryList, ...)`?

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old post but I needed to solve this issue and came across the post. dymmeh's solution was a good start but I wanted to sort in one pass and I wanted Windows-like sorting (case not considered). Here's what I came up with:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {

        if (lhs.isDirectory() == rhs.isDirectory()) { // Both files are directory OR file, compare by name
            return lhs.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.getName().toLowerCase());
        } else if (lhs.isDirectory()) { // Directories before files
            return -1;
        } else { // rhs must be a directory
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is straight forward:

```
final File file = new File(_directory);
final File[] files = file.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, new FileComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the variable to check the name is of file and folder, I can think of a way to sort them as per your requirement. Make two ArrayLists. Separate folders and files in these two ArrayList and then sort both according to the names, simple sort operation for string. Then simply append the files List at the end of Folder List. May be it will work. Seems simple.