# ArrayList sorting Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

```
private List<String> mitem = null;
private List<String> mpath = null;
String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

private void getDir() {
    mitem = new ArrayList<String>();
    mpath = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];
        if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
            mpath.add(file.getPath());
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // Folder names
                mitem.add(file.getName() + "/");
            } else {
                // File name
                mitem.add(file.getName());

            }
        }
    }
    fileList = new FileManagerAdapter(this, mitem, mpath);
    listview.setAdapter(fileList);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(onitemclick);
}
```

Here im adding the list of files and folders on some path to ArrayList, How to sort all folders first and all files at last. what kind of sorting technique should i use in order to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** CustomAdapter

```
public class FileManagerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List<String> mitem;
    private Context mContext;

    public FileManagerAdapter(Context context, List<String> item,
            List<String> path) {
        super(context, R.layout.fileadapter_list, item);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mitem = item;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fileadapter_list, null);
        }
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txtTitle.setText(mitem.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you facing any challenge approach you used so far?

Comment: yes, both files and folders are mixed. i wanted it to be in a sorted way. @kishorJoshi

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243450/sorting-of-files-according-to-file-or-folder

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code for sorting files in which type is also sorted:

```
protected void sortByNmDes(){
         fAdapter = new FolderAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.file_row, FileList);
         fAdapter.sort(new Comparator<File>() {

             @Override
                public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(lhs.isDirectory() && !rhs.isDirectory()){
                            return -1;
                    }else if(!lhs.isDirectory() && rhs.isDirectory()){
                            return 1;
                    }
                    return rhs.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(lhs.getName().toLowerCase());
                }
        });
         setListAdapter(fAdapter);
     }
```

where `FileList` is arraylist of Files.

Comment: can u explain a bit more.. because I'm using custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

use this approach 
List tempFilesList=>store all file names.
    List tempDirectoriesList=>store all directorynames.
    List FinalList=>add tempDirectoriesList then add tempFilesList to this FinalList.

I think i need not to tell how to add tempFilesList and tempDirectoriesList to FinalList.

Comment: mitem.addAll(mitem_folders); mitem.addAll(mitem_files); then i have set the adapter as using mitem, but still both files and folders are mixed.